# What type of 555 timer circuit is this

Tags: diodes, timer, 555

[image]

Could someone please describe what sort of 555 setup/circuit is in the image and how it operates. This is the webpage on which I found it http://www.thefintels.com/aer/protected/timer.htm 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have seen thousands of 555 circuits. With pin 7 open and pin 6 grounded, it maybe an attempt at a poor-mans oscillator with a 50% duty cycle. These are 'gimmick' circuits that may or may not work, and the duty cycle maybe far from 50%. This is an observation and not an answer, as it is something I would not build.

Comment: I know one thing for sure. The image is so badly drawn and confusing with the more than 20 year long availability of highly usable free tools, that any resource showing such should be left alone. Nobody _rightfully_ proud of their work should publish that image. (The fact alone @Sparky256 decoded 6 being at hard ground I think supports my opinion)

Comment: @Asmyldof. What a mess, and an irrational circuit as well. I vote for this to be closed, unless the OP comes up with a much cleaner and rational layout.

Comment: @Sparky256: Pin 6 isn't grounded, it's connected to pin 2 and to one end of the 47k\$\Omega\$ rheostat used to set the output frequency.

Comment: @EMFields. Ok. My bad. Still a goofy circuit.

Comment: Hi guys, how should I go about explaining what I want to do? I understand the circuit diagram is no good. I am building a parachute deployment timer.

Comment: I have a switch that momentarily closes when the rocket undergoes acceleration, a 555 in Bistable mode to latch the signal and a powerMos to sink enough current for a piece of nichrome wire. What I need is a timer circuit.

Comment: When the rocket's acceleration is no longer great enough to keep the switch closed, and it opens, how long after that do you want to wait before the parachute deploys?

Comment: @EMFields I was thinking of between 10 to 30 seconds, which can be adjusted with a pot. I think when I was searching I should have rather used the term "555 delay timer".

Comment: That might have helped, but there's many a slip 'twixt the cup and the lip, and you're talking rocket science, so what can you tell us about your rocket and the switch?

Comment: @EMFields well it is a G class motor and I expect it to go up about 700m, so I guess 18-22 seconds before deployment to be a safe window.   heres a link to the switch [link](http://www.uswaterrockets.com/construction_&_tutorials/g_switch/tutorial.htm)

Comment: So, if the switch closes when the rocket is launched and opens some time later, you want the parachute to be deployed about 20 seconds after the switch opens?

Comment: the switch will also oscillate if it undergoes significant de-acceleration as well, so 20 seconds after the switch closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a good circuit for your application, because as long as the switch is open the 555's output will be high, which will turn ON the MOSFET and deploy the parachute.

If all you need is a simple timer then this should work for you:

The trick here is that since U1 fires with a low on the trigger input, pin 2 is held high by R2 until S1, (the spring switch) connects the R1C1 junction to ground. This will pull R2 and U1-2 low, momentarily, which will start the timer.

When that happens, U1-3 will go high and U1-7 will go open-collector, allowing C2 to charge toward Vcc through R3.

When C2 charges enough that the voltage on U1-6 rises to 1/3Vcc, U1-3 will time out forcing U1-3 and U1-7 low, which will discharge C2 and end the timing cycle until U1-2 receives another low-going pulse.

The time that VOUT stays high is determined by RV1 and C2, and is given by

$$ t = 1.1RC,$$

which in this case is about 23 seconds with the pot cranked about halfway through its range of travel.

R3 and C3 are used to make sure the timer resets and its output stays low when U1 is powered up, C4 is used to decouple the 555 from the supply if it's a bipolar 555. if it's a CMOS 555 it can be eliminated. R1 is used for DC restoration around C1 and, finally, R4 is used to limit the current into U1-7 in case the pot gets cranked all the way to Vcc.

[image]